# Hierarchy Taxonomy Import with fields

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, importing-exporting

I have been trying to import my taxonomies (structure with fields) via Taxonomy CSV import/export module and was able to import it but I am having difficulties when trying to import the fields (id) too. To clarify further, below is the structure of my taxonomy and data sample (The excel table I am trying to import).

Data sample (Data around 5k rows):

```
Rosera  AA07    Bouer   AA0703     Dana     AA070301
Malina  AA02    Azazi   AA0200     Daman    AA020002
Malina  AA02    Azazi   AA0200     Haritan  AA020003
Malina  AA02    Azazi   AA0200     Haritan  AA020003
Malina  AA02    Afrin   AA0203     Afrin    AA020300
Malina  AA02    Cerlo   AA0204     Aghtrin  AA020401
```

I imported the term structure as below (in the same vocabulary):

```
-Rosera
  -Bouer
    -Dana
-Malina
  -Azazi
    -Daman
    -Haritan
  -Afrin
    -Afrin
  -Cerlo
    -Aghtrin
```

I have added "ID" field in my vocabulary to import ID to it for each term.

Problem: How can I import the ids to the terms I imported?

Comment: check this link http://www.webwash.net/tutorials/intro-taxonomy-csv-part-2-import-terms-custom-fields

Comment: thanks for the link. I've already checked it and downloaded the DEV version of the module, however, I am not able to add the field ID to the terms

Comment: For D8, see: [Term CSV Export Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_csv_export_import).